# Google vision APi labels decrease the labels percentages

Tags: java, android, google-vision, vision-api

I would like  to use the Google Vision API for label detection. But I want to decrease the labels percentages and I do not know how I can do this. Could someone help me? I am using a sample. I'm using a sample for android that google makes available
This is the code:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/blob/master/android/CloudVision/app/src/main/java/com/google/sample/cloudvision/MainActivity.java

And this and that aside it displays the results:

```
 // add the features we want
     annotateImageRequest.setFeatures(new ArrayList<Feature>() {{
                            Feature labelDetection = new Feature();
                            labelDetection.setType("LABEL_DETECTION");
                            labelDetection.setMaxResults(10);
                            add(labelDetection);
                        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you'd like to show more results (labels)? If this is the case, just increase `MAX_LABEL_RESULTS` value (the default is set to 10).

In code snippet you posted you just need to change `labelDetection.setMaxResults(10);` for example to `labelDetection.setMaxResults(15);`